# Adsense reload ajax

Tags: adsense

I know that this question is here many times, but it is a litlte bit old. So my question is eas. Is there any right way to reload google adsense ad? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: not sure what you mean by reload a google adsense ad, every time you reload the page you should get a new add

Comment: I get content for the page via ajax, so I need reload ad too